# Hierarchical ordinal regression (or ranking) with prediction constraints on clusters?

Tags: classification, mixed-model, predictive-models, ordinal-data, ranking

I am interested in predicting an ordered outcome of 0,1,2 or 3 (0<1<2<3) for individual responses in a bunch of different clusters. In each cluster $i$ of size $n_i$ there is a single 3, 2 and 1 allocated to group of responses, the remaining $n_i-3$ responses are set to 0. To clarify, the situation is as follows: 3,2,1 votes are given to the 1st, 2nd and 3rd best players in a match and 0 to the remainder, each match represents a cluster.

My overall goal is to predict the number of votes obtained by each individual after say, $N$ matches (on a new dataset).

Now the first thing I thought to do was a mixed-effects ordinal regression, where each match/cluster has a random intercept. But using this formulation, there is no guarantee that it allocates the 3,2,1 and 0's predictions to individuals in a new cluster in the way that it should.

The are two primary ways I thought to solve this problem:

1. Just give the 'expected' number of votes to each player in the new cluster based on the predicted probability of being in each class. (I think this is the way to go)
2. Just allocate the 3,2,1, scores to the individuals in each cluster who have the highest probability of obtaining a 3. The rest get 0's.

At this point, my big concern is that what it takes to get votes in one match/cluster could be considerably different from what it takes to get votes in another match, as the 3,2,1 votes must be allocated regardless of the performances of the individuals in the match relative to other matches. I imagine a random intercept for match may alleviate this issue, but is there a better way to deal with it? This is less of a problem with (2) that allocates the 3,2,1 votes regardless, while (1) may allocate less or more than the 6 'expected' votes per match. (But this might not actually be an issue?)

Is ordinal regression an appropriate approach? Are the ranking based methods discussed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_to_rank#List_of_methods) appropriate? The way I see it is, the method I use doesn't need to allocate the 3,2,1,0 votes, if the method's output is a ranking for each match/cluster. Once the ranking is obtained, it is easy to allocate the votes.

Is there anything else I should or need to consider?